# Создание родительского класса для реализации RecyclerView

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте! Имею вот такой фрагмент кода, который применяется более чем в 10-ти фрагментах, подскажите как его можно стандартизировать, что бы его можно было вызвать одной-двумя строками. Я так понимаю необходимо реализовывать интерфейс обратного вызова, но не совсем понимаю как это реализовать.

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private LinearLayoutManager layoutManager;

private BookListAdapter bookListAdapter;
private List<Book> bookList = new ArrayList<>();

public MyFragment() { }

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
    final Context context = getActivity();

    tests();
    Log.e("Hrre ","qwertyuio " + bookList.get(2).getAuthor());

    bookListAdapter = new BookListAdapter(context, bookList);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);

    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

    recyclerView.setAdapter(bookListAdapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    // bookListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    return view;
}
```

}

Comment: не совсем понятен вопрос. Вы хотите узнать, как вставить его 10 раз в разметку или программно? Если фрагмент прописан и должным образом вставлен, дополнительно обращаться к нему не нужно.

Comment: а какие-то функции во фрагменте будут изменяться, а какие-то оставаться базовыми?

Comment: @Jarvis_J, Хотел исключить копирование кода во всех фрагментах, и упростить будущую поддержку. хотел сделать что-то на подобие:  class Fragment_1 extends MyFragment { public void myMethods() {  bookList = getBookList();  myFragment(bookList);  }  }

Comment: по правилам хорошего кода booklist вообще лучше хранить отдельно и создавать фрагмент через `newInstance`, передавая туда аргументом позицию списка. И при необходимости получать booklist оттуда, где он хранится. Удобный паттерн MCV. Если вам нужна реализация именно с наследованием, напишите, что именно не получается в вашем варианте (с `extends`)?

Comment: @Jarvis_J, я новичок, стремлюсь к реализации паттерна MVP, возможно я что-то делаю не так в связи с пробелами в понимании того или иного вопроса данного патерна и ООП в целом. Не подскажите ли хорошую статейку о том что вы говорили.

Comment: вот хорошая большая книжка по этому (и не только) поводу: http://infasoft.com/library/books/18166-fillips-b-styuart-k-marsikano-k-android-programmirovanie-dlya-professionalov-3-e-izdanie.html . Ну и касательно вашего вопроса, сейчас напишу ответ на то как я понял вопрос

Comment: У вас во всех 10-ти фрагментах будет список, который выводит книги? Где здесь 50 строк одинакового кода и что в фрагментах различается.

Comment: @Jarvis_J, извините, погорячился, сейчас в 2/3 кода меньше. Да, во всех фрагментах будет список выводящий книги, использующий одну и туже разметку

Comment: Тогда вам скорее всего вовсе не нужно 10 фрагментов, а нужен только один, который будет выводить нужные книги. В чем разница списков книг для разных фрагментов? Если у вас одинаковая разметка и логика, то вам просто нужно в один и тот же фрагмент передавать разные наборы данных, которые он должен отобразить, а не делать под каждый набор отдельный фрагмент и думать над тем, как их упростить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Делаете BaseFragment (например) который в свою очередь наследуется от Fragmen.
В этом BaseFragment реализуете всю логика которая повторяется, потом каждый новый фрагмент в котором есть такая же логика наследуете от BaseFragment и все. Если Вам необходимы какие-то методы BaseFragment вызывать непосредственно из наследника задайте свойство видимости для нужных методов protected. Это базовые вещи Java ООП.

Comment: Видимо здесь в вопросе классическая проблема XY. Дело в том, что человеку в вопросе нужны полностью одинаковые классы, в которых [отличаются только данные](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/813572/Создание-родительского-класса-для-реализации-recyclerview#comment1291207_813572) (разные наборы книг), которые нужно вывести на экран. Это решается не наследованием, а передачей данных в один и тот же класс. Человек не очень понимает, как именно решается его задача, стоит подождать, когда он снова появится и прояснит, в чем именно его проблема, а не его [неправильное] представление о ее решении.

Comment: )) Ну тогда ждем пояснений автора

Comment: BaseFragment, это то что мне нужно. Только я не могу понять как его мне реализовать и как вызвать.

Comment: Вот что должно получиться: есть одно активити, которое имеет несколько фрагментов: жанры, поиск, новинки и т.д., есть второе активити: которое также имеет жанры, новинки, и т.д., но уже с другой логикой работы. Но они все будут визуально иметь одинаковое оформление, это будет RecyclerView с CardView, которые будут программно формироваться из нескольких разметок (что-то на подобие динамической разметки в вебпрограммировании). Соответственно зачем мне писать в каждом фрагменте реализацию фрагмента которая приведена выше, хотя она будет идентичной для всех.

Comment: @Valeriy если это будет 10 идентичных фрагментов, зачем их от чего то наследовать. Используйте один и тот же фрагмент, это так трудно понять разве. Никто не делает отдельный фрагмент, чтобы выести на экран жанры, другой - новинки и тд, если все это одно и тоже, но отсортированно или отфильтровано по разному.

Comment: Каждый фрагмент выводит разные данные и логи их получения отличается кардинально. В одном активити они приходят с БД, в котором в принципе можно так реализовать, в другом же это будут данные с интернета. Новинки это из одного источника, жанры из другого, поиск выполнен по третьему. При этом необходимо научиться и придерживаться паттерна MVP, логика которого мне наиболее понятна и вполне подходит для этого технического задания.

Answer (score 1):

Храните ваш список отдельно от всего. В упрощении паттерна MVC:

```
public class BookLab {

private static BookLab bookLab;
private ArrayList<Book> books;
private ArrayList<Book> books2;
private ArrayList<Book> books3;
...

public static BookLab get(Context ctx) {
    if (bookLab== null) bookLab= new BookLab (ctx);
    return bookLab;
}

private BookLab (Context ctx) {
    books = new ArrayList<>();
    String [] books_names = ctx.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.ваш array из ресурсов);

    for (int i=0;i<book_names.lenght;i++){
        Book book = new Book();
        book.setName(book_names[i]);
        books.add(book);
    }

    повторить для остальных books

}

ArrayList<Book> getBooks (int number){
    switch(number){
         case 1: return books;
         case 2: return books1;
         case 3: return books2;
    }
}
```

Класс Book:

```
public class Book {
private String name, description;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}
}
```

Во фрагменте:

```
public static MyFragment newInstance(int number) {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("number", number);
    MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment ();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

onCreateView(...){
    number_of_list = getArguments().getInt("number",0)
    myList = BookLab.get(getActivity()).getBooks(number_of_list);

}

int getNumberOfList(){
    return number_of_list;
}
```

Достать список из другого места: `BookLab.get(getActivity()).getBooks(MyFragment.getNumberOfList());`

Comment: благодарю, но это немного не то, хотя для меня будет полезно. Я хотел упростить непосредственно реализацию фрагментов, что бы в каждом фрагменте не создавать 30-50 строк одинакового кода, которые в будущем будет проблематично изменять и дополнять, ведь их таких будет более 10 классов (фрагментов). А так нужно изменить анимацию, изменил в родительском и всё отлично, нужно переделать тени, пожалуйста и т.д. Ведь все фрагменты находятся в одном приложении и должны себя вести плюс/минус одинаково, что-бы не вызывать ошеломление у пользователя

Comment: А) а в чем тогда проблема с `extends`?

Comment: я так понимаю вы создаёте класс содержащий в себе все массивы, и оттуда уже достаёте их. Это делается для упрощения доступа к данным?

Comment: проблема в том что я не могу понять как в дочернем классе вызвать родительский класс и передать ему выводимые значения.  Вызывать нужно    onCreate()    или    onCreateView()    и что им необходимо передавать? И как им передать мой массив?

Comment: если вы работаете с наследником к родителю обращаться не нужно. Если вы хотите переписать какую-то родительскую переменную или функцию - делайте `@Override myFunction` (или `myVar`, определенная в паренте, = нужное значение.

Comment: Класс для связи объектов с их отображением, где бы оно не случилось. Да, паттерны все для упрощения ;)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75962/discussion-between-jarvis-j-and-valeriy).